# Need to randomize Array of Strings to be returned as both ques. and answer for jeopardy program

Tags: java, arrays, string, swing, random

```
   String[] am = new String[10];

   am[0] = "Sam";
   am[1] = "Sam";
   am[2] = "Sam";
   am[3] = "Sam";
   am[4] = "Sam";
   am[5] = "Sam";
   am[6] = "Sam";
   am[7] = "Sam";
   am[8] = "Sam";
   am[9] = "Sam";
```

For a jeopardy game, random questions per GUI Jpanel button click

Comment: Random won't appear very random if every item of the array says "Sam".  BTW What is your question?

Comment: Yea i know this is just a template.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to write a parallel array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22122100/how-to-write-a-parallel-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Approach 1: Shuffling the list**

You can shuffle your list using:

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(am);
Collections.shuffle(list);
```

Even better is starting with an ArrayList, and adding your possibilites to that ArrayList, completely ignoring the String[] array

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("value1");
list.add("value2");
...
Collections.shuffle(list);
```

You can then retreive an element from the shuffeled list using `get(index)`, i.e. :

```
String random = list.get(0);
```

**Approach 2: Randomizing the index**

If you insist on using the String[]-array, you can do

```
String random = am[new Random().nextInt(am.length)]
```

This will create a `Random`-object, and generate a random integer ranging from 0 to the length of your array minus one. Once this integer is generated, it will be used as an index for to get an element from your String[]-array.

You can use the same approach on an ArrayList:

```
String random = list.get(new Random().nextInt(list.size));
```

Comment: Your second option seems to work bset for me! Thanks for the response.